# Compare values within a group in SQL

Tags: oracle9i

I want to search within a group and compare two values and return the records where a match is found for both. For example if my table looks like below -

```
ID   Country  Account
1      US     1111_AA
1      US     1111
2      AU     2222_BB
2      HT     2222_BB
3      DE     4444_CC
3      DE     5555_DD
```

In the above example, I want to group on ID and then check within the group if the country value and the account value (for account only first 4 characters need to be looked at) match then return the ID where a match is found. Query will return only ID 1 in this case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a join back to the same table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM Accounts t1
JOIN Accounts t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID
AND t2.Country = t1.Country
AND t2.Account <> t1.Account
AND t2.Account = SubStr(t1.Account, 1, 4);
```